# Can't get jQuery Waypoints working

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla2.5, jquery-waypoints

I've been fighting it for 6 hours or so and still can't make it work.
I have Joomla 2.5 with T3 Framework v 2.1.0 with Bootstrap 3.

I want this plugin actually to perform an easy stuff, no sophisticated animation or sliders, just want to achieve what is shown on the site of the developer
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

At first, I embedded the code as said in the documentation

```
<script src="/path/to/js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/path/to/js/waypoints-sticky.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/path/to/js/waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My **markup** as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="itemIWantToStick"></div>
</div>
```

Then I added the **code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.itemIWantToStick').waypoint('sticky');
});
</script>
```

In the `waypoints-sticky.js` I got the code:

```
this, function($) {
    var defaults, wrap;
    defaults = {
      wrapper: '<div class="wrapper" />',
      stuckClass: 'stuck'
    };
```

In the css I got:

```
.sticky{
    width: 25%;
}
.wrapper{
    display: block;
}
.stuck{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

But I can't get it work. Maybe the jQuery libraries conflict with those I have by default in Joomla and T3 stuff?
I read every question regarding the topic here and browsed the web and still was not able to solve it.

Maybe I'm missing something. Since I'm only beggining to explore the JS. Could you please tell me what's wrong with it.
Any help is appreciated a lot.

P.S. I also tried to use the data from [Here](http://www.pressbeau.co.uk/newsandevents), I replaced everything so as my stuff match with the example's. Also tried to use data and settings from the dev's site - still hopeless.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `waypoints.js` before the sticky extension. Your post, if accurate, shows you are including the sticky shortcut first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `defaults` directly inside your `waypoints-sticky.js` like this:

```
$('.itemIWantToStick').waypoint('sticky', {
    wrapper: '<div class="wrapper" />',
    stuckClass: 'stuck'
});
```

Comment: Still no change at all. It doesn't even create a class for the item I want to stick.